# How to read integers from file with integers and strings in C

Tags: c, file-handling

I am reading a .txt file which contains data in a random form i.e. it contains integers and strings mixed in it.

**Sample `.txt` file:**

```
this is a 22 string 33 sorry222 stack33ing
still yysi288 2nd line
```

I want to read the file and differentiate all valid string i.e. which do not contain integers concatinated with them. And store those strings in an array.

Any leads on how to differentiate?

Comment: You could read space-delimited words and check if the word have any [digits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) in it.

Comment: Could you kindly provide a small working prototype @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Those aren't "integers" (as in, they aren't raw `int` values) - those are textual representations in base-10 using (presumably ASCII) digit characters.

Comment: "Could you kindly provide a small working prototype" - yes, if you'll agree to my consulting fee :)

Comment: Do you know how to use the `scanf` function? Do you know anything about [the C input/output functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) (like e.g. [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen))? Then check out [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). And all of this should be part of any decent beginners text-book or tutorial or class.

Comment: @abdulwasey20 You want to differentiate the "strings" you see, but technically these aren´t valid separated strings in the file. It is just one whole string which has space characters in.

Comment: @RobertS well i meant i want to differentiate the words in it. like "this" "is" "a" "string" etc.

Comment: What do you know how to do? Do you know how to read a line of text into a buffer? Do you know how to do that no matter how long the line of text is? Do you know how to examine strings to find where spaces are? Do you know how to check whether a character in a string is a digit?

Comment: I want to know after I have the whole file in a char array ( I know this far), how to identify a valid word and store it elsewhere(in another array) @EricPostpischil

Comment: Presumably your definition of "word" is "whitespace separated".  I'm not sure if you care about other punctuation characters, or if your files are limited to letters, digits, and whitespace.  One simpleminded way of reading arbitrary, free-form, whitespace-separated "words" like this is `scanf` with the format specifier `%s`. You'll be limited on the size of the words you can read by the size of the buffer you allocate for the job, but if you use, say, a length-limited specifier like `%99s` you can do so safely.  Then check each word to see if it contains a digit -- one easy way is `strpbrk`.

Comment: @abdulwasey20: Once you have the entire file in an array of `char`, scan the string: Examine each character. If it is a character that separates words, like a space or a tab or a new-line (likely any character `x` for which `isspace((unsigned char) x)` is true), then remember where it is. Then find the next character that separates words (or the end of the file contents). Then, if there are any characters between the two, test whether they are all digits. If they are, it is a decimal numeral. Start with that, and then make sure you are handling the beginning correctly.

Comment: Research `scanf("%d"`...` and `fgetc()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use #include <ctype.h> for that purpose.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int checkString( const char s[] ) {
    unsigned char c;
    while ( ( c = *s ) && ( isalpha( c ) || isblank( c ) ) ) ++s;
    return *s == '\0'; 
}



void printNonNumericWords(char str[]) {
int init_size = strlen(str);
char delim[] = " ";

char *ptr = strtok(str, delim);

while(ptr != NULL)
{
    if (checkString(ptr)) 
    printf("'%s'\n", ptr);


    ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Call function like this.

```
printNonNumericWords(this is a 22 string 33 sorry222 stack33ing");
```

Answer (score 0):

First: I can´t write the programm for you. It is your task to do and beside this i can´t even change things on your code or at least suggest to alter, because you are not providing any code. I can give you only a dusty leading algorithm for this case:

All the words you might see, are not valid strings in the file. It is only one string containing white space characters between each sequence of characters which appear for you as one word or separated string, but it doesn´t.

You have to get the whole string from the file first and store it into an `char` array, lets name it `source`, using `fgets()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *input;
char source[200];

input = fopen("text.txt","r");

fgets(source, 200, input);
```

After that you need to make those "words" separated strings by transport each of the characters of the source string, one after another, to other `char` arrays and quit writing the characters to them as soon as the space character or the NUL-byte after the last word is provided in the source string. Don´t forget to make a Nul-Byte (\n) terminating each string.

Thereafter you check each, now valid and separated string, if it either is a string that contains numbers or a string without any number.